# SharePoint 2019 Min role question

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, farm, sharepoint-farm

I am migrating SP 2013 to SP 2019. As everybody knows we cannot migrate directly SP 2013 to SP 2019, so I have make single server farm of SP 2016 and migrated SP 2013 to SP 2019.

Then I make SP 2019 Farm with below Min Role

1. UAT01 (Front-End with Distributed Cache)
2. UAT03 (Application)
3. UAT04 (Application)
4. UAT06 (Search)

At the moment UAT02 we have SP 2016, as I am in middle of migration we keep it, once we test all and everything okay then we will remove SP 2016 from UAT02 and install SP 2019 with min role of Front-End with Distributed Cache

Anyhow that was not my question. Kindly find below snap shot from my farm.

[image]

As we can see that

1. UAT01 is Front-End min role still it have **Metadata, secure store and user profile service on it**. *Why this services are on it.*
2. UAT03 and UAT04 is Application min role still it have **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation WebApplication**. *Why this services are on it.*
3. Most important when I create new web application it also creates on UAT03 and UAT04.

I want to understand that is it correct behavior of SharePoint 2019 and why  it is not giving any warning error of min roles to fix and it is showing complaint correctly

Please give proper and experience reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you check the docs document on the MinRole: [Description of MinRole and associated services in SharePoint Servers 2016 and 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/description-of-minrole-and-associated-services-in-sharepoint-server-2016)

Basically this is how MSFT design these services. When you select a MinRole other than custom, so we cant disable any service which is default to that role. If any service is stopped then nightly health rule fix that and bring the server to compliant.

yes it will create the web application on 3 & 4 servers but those web-application will not be accessible to the end user.

but if you want to disable permanently then you have to select the Custom role and choose the services.

Comment: So you mean to say custom role have more control and is it advisable to disable services as i mention.  Like disabling Metadata, secure store and user profile service on UAT01. 

And You mention UAT3 and 4 web-application will not be accessible to the end user then why it is created any reason !! and disabling on UAT3 and 4 is advisable

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes custom role have more control but it is not advisable to use it unless you really need it. MinRole designed to optimize performance of the servers. if you feel these services are creating problem then you can but otherwise no.

Comment: Agreed, it is not recommended to disable these services. Use the respective MinRole unless you have a very good reason not to, and it doesn't appear that there is, in this case.